# Selecting columns from a list of dataframes if they don't all have the desired columns in R

Tags: dataframe

I have a list of 438 dataframes in R. I need to select some specific columns from those dataframes. More specifically, I would like each of the 438 dataframes to be reduced just to the columns that I choose. However, the problem is that not all of the dataframes have the columns that I'm interested in. Moreover, those dataframes that do have the columns that I'm interested in don't have **all** of those columns, but just some of them.

My main idea of handling this was using a for loop. However, using the `subset()` or `select()` functions, or simply trying to use `[,]` with the column names in quotes after the comma in the for loop always returns the `Undefined columns selected` or `Unknown column` error - naturally, because I'm trying to subset some dataframes to the columns they don't have.

What would be the best way to solve this issue? It's really painful to go through the 438 dataframes manually.

Edit: I tried merging all the dataframes into one dataframe because I could easily select those variables after the merge, but my computer doesn't have enough memory.

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: R - Sorry, edited!